# How to delete an object by using PK in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

How do I delete an object without fetching it from the db first?

In another ORM, I can do this:

```
session.Delete<User>(1); // 1 = PK
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add the following class to your project:

```
public static class SessionHelper
{
    public static void Delete<TEntity>(this ISession session, object id)
    {
        var queryString = string.Format("delete {0} where id = :id",
                                        typeof(TEntity));
        session.CreateQuery(queryString)
               .SetParameter("id", id)
               .ExecuteUpdate();
    }
}
```

You can now use `session.Delete<User>(1)`.

Comment: Will this also work if name of my primary key column is something different than "id"?

Comment: @A_J Yes. `id` is a special name that represents the entitiy's id. See http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryhql.html#queryhql-where.

Comment: Why not just `session.Delete(session.Query<User>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id));`?

Comment: @HristoYankov that's an extra, unnecessary query

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon, but isn't it `IQueryable`, which would translate to proper SQL statement, like `WHERE`. I would expect the whole thing to translate to `DELETE FROM USERS WHERE ID = 1`.

Comment: @HristoYankov FirstOrDefault executes the query. But NHibernate 5 DOES offer a way to delete in one shot with a LINQ extension. See http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html#querylinq-modifying-delete

Answer (score 7):

You could do this

```
User user = new User();
user.Id = 1;
session.Delete(user);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var user = session.Load<User>(1);
session.Delete(user);
```

`Load` will create a proxy for the User object with the identifier set. I'm not sure if `Delete` will load the object from the database before deleting it and I'm unable to test it at the moment.

Comment: Load is not Get! Load just creates a Proxy for the actual object. It's just a box with an Id. Get actually loads the record from the database. So, no, it doesn't "actually" load anything from the db, as long as you read only the id property.

Comment: The "load" will not load the user as you said. But the Delete will, always.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the ExecuteUpdate method on the IQuery object.

```
IQuery q = session.CreateQuery ("delete from User where Id = 1");
q.ExecuteUpdate();
```

Should delete the object without retrieving it afaik.

Answer (score 0):

prior to ver 2 there wasn't a way.
After ver 2 you have the `ExecuteUpdate()` method on `IQuery` and there is an overloaded method on `ISession.Delete()` where it accepts a string that defines a deletion query

Comment: Maybe true in 2010 but nowadays there are more and better options as well

Comment: @LuisFilipe: And those are...??