# NHibernate Delete best practice

Tags: .net, nhibernate

What's the best practice in NHibernate to delete an object by id. You can do both

```
public void Delete(int id) 
{
    Session.Delete(new MyEntity { Id = id });
}
```

Or you could do

```
public void Delete(int id) 
{
    var entity = Session.Get<MyEntity>(id);
    Session.Delete(entity);
}
```

The second option feels cleaner to me, because you're not composing a new object just for deletion, but on the other hand you'll execute two SQL commands, instead of one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete an object by using PK in nhibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063777/how-to-delete-an-object-by-using-pk-in-nhibernate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option is the best practice. NHibernate needs to load the object before deleting it so that it cascade deletes through the object graph. I would rather do a direct SQL delete than create a bogus object to trick NHibernate as in the first option.